# Untouchable state

Tags: lg-g2

When I connect my device with USB to Windows PC it shows as

> Marshall London HS-USB Diagnostics 9006

at device manager. Windows finds multiple device partitions and asks if I want to format them.

Device cannot boot properly. **I cannot enter download mode or do factory reset with button combinations**. Screen shows LG logo for a while and then goes dark (backlights still on). While logo is still up, it shows

> Boot certification verify

message.

I have tried to connect to device with multiple tools, including ADB/Fastboot with no luck.

I got there by doing factory reset on rooted device. I got that message before I was doing factory reset and device booted just fine.

How do I connect to my device in order to flash its firmware? Or might be just restore to previous state? What does that boot certification message mean?

Comment: http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2432476 Follow these steps. Be careful to download the correct kdz for your phone (eg 802 is pure open market G2)

Comment: I cannot execute that method because step 4 asks to enter in download mode which I cannot do. That tool will not be able to connect to my device. Thank you for your response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This post can be used as reference http://forum.xda-developers.com/lg-g2/general/lg-g2-unbrickable-fix-real-hard-brick-t2904404

Shorting capacitor c5004 switched device to QDLoader 9008. From there I was able to use BoardDiag v2.99a to fix this issue. Other versions of this tool gave me some errors.